# Error in facebook api using php SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am using facebook PHP SDK to access the friend list

```
    include_once("../fb-config.php");
    include_once("../facebook.php");

 try{

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID',
   'secret' => 'FACEBOOK_SECRET',
   'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
 ));
 $uid=$facebook->getUser();
 $data = $facebook->api( array( 'method' => 'friends.getappusers') );
 var_dump($data);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->__toString();
  }
```

i get the following error

> Exception: 104: Requires valid
>   signature

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your App ID and App Secret are correct and also your website URL matches the one which you inserted when you was creating application over facebook using Developer app.